# spring data load children and query by child property

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am using spring-data-jpa/hibernate/mysql

```
class A{
   private long id;
   private Collection<B> myBs;
}

class B{
   private long id;
   private int property;
}
```

I want to load an A with `myBs` collection loaded with all `B`s where `B.property > 5`

so I did this:

```
private interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long>{

 @Query("SELECT a, b "
        + "FROM A a JOIN a.myBs b ON b.property > :prop"
        + "WHERE a.id= :id ")
 public A getByIdPastB(@Param("id") long id, @Param("prop") Integer prop);
}
```

however I get exception that too many As are retrieved from data store. Basically, it retrieved table

```
_______________________________
A.id  | B.id  | B.a_id| B.prop
2     | 1     | 2     | 8
2     | 2     | 2     | 11
2     | 3     | 2     | 7
```

and instead of building one A object and populating with 3 B objects, it is trying to build 3 A objects with one B object each.

Now I know fetch graphs manage to tell JPA to be smart about it, however here it did not work. How can I set it up to do it properly? Is there a way to do naming like

`private A findWhereMyBsPropGreaterThan(Integer prop)` and then just put an `@EntityGraph` annotation on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here it is:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name="full", attributeNodes={@NamedAttributeNode("myBs")})
class A{
}

@EntityGraph("full)
@Query("SELECT a"
        + "FROM A a JOIN a.myBs b ON b.property > :prop"
        + "WHERE a.id= :id ")
public A getByIdPastB(@Param("id") long id, @Param("prop") Integer prop);
```